# Split an array of objects into smaller arrays based on the arrays of ids Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an initial array of objects and 2 arrays of ids as following:

```js
const arr = [
  { id: 1, name: "John" },
  { id: 7, name: "Alice" },
  { id: 10, name: "Ken" },
  { id: 5, name: "Bob" },
  { id: 2, name: "Kevin" },
  { id: 6, name: "Tony" },
  { id: 3, name: "Harry" },
  { id: 4, name: "Kyle" },
  { id: 8, name: "Jane" },
  { id: 9, name: "Sam" },
];
const list1 = [1, 4, 2];
const list2 = [3, 8, 9, 10];
```

What I want is 2 new sub arrays of `arr` which include the objects having the respective id in `list1` and `list2`. Notice that the order of objects of two new sub arrays must be **as the same order** of ids in `list1` and `list2`.

I have tried the below way, it works but may not be effective with a large number of items in `arr`:

```js
const subArr1 = [];
const subArr2 = [];

list1.forEach((id) => {
  const idx = arr.findIndex((item) => item.id === id);
  if (idx !== -1 && subArr1.findIndex((item) => item.id === id) === -1) {
    subArr1.push(arr[idx]);
  }
});
list2.forEach((id) => {
  const idx = arr.findIndex((item) => item.id === id);
  if (idx !== -1 && subArr2.findIndex((item) => item.id === id) === -1) {
    subArr2.push(arr[idx]);
  }
});


/* Result:
subArr1 = [
  { id: 1, name: "John" },
  { id: 4, name: "Kyle" },
  { id: 2, name: "Kevin" },
];
subArr2 = [
  { id: 3, name: "Harry" },
  { id: 8, name: "Jane" },
  { id: 9, name: "Sam" },
  { id: 10, name: "Ken" },
];
*/
```

Beside my idea, is there any better solution?

### Updated:

The `Array.prototype.filter()` and `Array.prototype.includes()` works to create 2 new sub arrays but the order also should be the same as order of ids in `list1` and `list2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```js
const filterByIds = (arr, ids) => ids.map(id => arr.find(e => e.id === id)).filter(e => e);
```

The `.filter(e => e)` is optional if you don't want `undefined` in your list when the id is not found.

```js
const arr = [
  { id: 1, name: "John" },
  { id: 7, name: "Alice" },
  { id: 10, name: "Ken" },
  { id: 5, name: "Bob" },
  { id: 2, name: "Kevin" },
  { id: 6, name: "Tony" },
  { id: 3, name: "Harry" },
  { id: 4, name: "Kyle" },
  { id: 8, name: "Jane" },
  { id: 9, name: "Sam" },
];
const list1 = [1, 4, 2];
const list2 = [3, 8, 9, 10];

const filterByIds = (arr, ids) => ids.map(id => arr.find(e => e.id === id)).filter(e => e);

const arr1 = filterByIds(arr, list1);
console.log(arr1);

const arr2 = filterByIds(arr, list2);
console.log(arr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const subArr1 = list1.map((id) => arr.find((item) => item.id === id));
const subArr2 = list2.map((id) => arr.find((item) => item.id === id));
```

Comment: How about the order of objects, it should be fit the order of 2 lists of ids `list1` and `list2`.

Comment: sorry, forgot the order. use `map` instead

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of your code?

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr = [
  { id: 1, name: 'John' },
  { id: 7, name: 'Alice' },
  { id: 10, name: 'Ken' },
  { id: 5, name: 'Bob' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Kevin' },
  { id: 6, name: 'Tony' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Harry' },
  { id: 4, name: 'Kyle' },
  { id: 8, name: 'Jane' },
  { id: 9, name: 'Sam' },
];

const list1 = [1, 4, 2];
const list2 = [3, 8, 9, 10];

const subArr1 = arr.filter((item) => list1.includes(item.id));
const subArr2 = arr.filter((item) => list2.includes(item.id));

console.log({
  subArr1,
  subArr2,
});

/**
 * Output:
 * {
  subArr1: [
    { id: 1, name: 'John' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Kevin' },
    { id: 4, name: 'Kyle' }
  ],
  subArr2: [
    { id: 10, name: 'Ken' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Harry' },
    { id: 8, name: 'Jane' },
    { id: 9, name: 'Sam' }
  ]
}
 */
```

in above code consists of an array arr containing objects with id and name properties. There are also two additional arrays, list1 and list2, which contain some IDs.

The goal of the code is to filter the arr array based on the IDs present in list1 and list2, resulting in two sub-arrays: subArr1 and subArr2.

Here's a step-by-step breakdown of the solution:

- Initialize an empty array subArr1 to store the filtered objects from arr based on the IDs in list1.
- Use the filter method on the arr array to iterate over each object.
- For each object, use the includes method on list1 to check if the id - of the object exists in list1.
- If the object's id is present in list1, it will return true and be included in the subArr1 array.
- Repeat the same steps to create subArr2 by filtering arr based on the IDs in list2.

After executing the code, subArr1 will contain the objects from arr with IDs 1, 4, and 2, while subArr2 will contain the objects with IDs 3, 8, 9, and 10.

By using the filter method and the includes method, we can easily filter the array of objects based on specific IDs and store the filtered objects in separate sub-arrays.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include an explanation of your code.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).